# Calculate bandwidth of wide-band FM from spectrum graph

Tags: signal, communication, signal-processing, matlab

I want to calculate the bandwidth of my signal  output from the graph it results from application of the FFT.
[image]

I can apply the Carlson formula  knowing that I have all the parameters :$$B = 2(\beta +1 )fm$$ ,but what about the graphical solution ?

Comment: So what's beta and fm? What do you calculate with Carson? What do you measure from the spectrum? Are they the same? Now what's your question?

Comment: Beta is the modulation index ,and the fm is the frequency of the modulated signal . Sorry I had to precise it before

Comment: Numerically, what is your beta and fm? Put those numbers into Carson and tell us what numerically you get. Now look at the graph, and locate the lowest and highest modulation harmonics, and read off their frequencies. Subtract one from the other. What's the indicated bandwidth? Is that the same as Carson?